# Troubles computing Type I error with Anova in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm trying to compute the type I error for a simple Anova test and I'm getting strange results.

let's assume that I want to detect the impact of dose (DOSE) on an observed variable (obs) in 4 different hospitals (HOP).
Under the hypothesis that the drug doesn't impact the observed variable but the hospital do I can produce a dataset like that:

```
data.frame(
obs=c(rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1)),
HOP=rep(1:4,100),
DOSE=rep(c(0,15,30,50),each=100))->data
```

I can then test using an anova the effect of dose on the observed variable and extract the p value:

```
summary(aov(data$obs~data$DOSE))[[1]][[5]][1]->pvalue
```

If I do it 100 times and I sum the number of times that the pvalue is lower or equal 0.05 I will get the Type I error and this value should be equal to 5:

```
 Allp<-NULL
for (i in 1:100){
data.frame(
obs=c(rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1)),
HOP=rep(1:4,100),
DOSE=rep(c(0,15,30,50),each=100))->data
summary(aov(data$obs~data$DOSE))[[1]][[5]][1]->pvalue
Allp<-rbind(Allp,pvalue)}
sum(Allp<=0.05)
```

**However it equals 0 or 1!**

I tried assuming no impact of the hospital:

```
Allp<-NULL
for (i in 1:100){
data.frame(
obs=c(rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,0,1)),
HOP=rep(1:4,100),
DOSE=rep(c(0,15,30,50),each=100))->data
summary(aov(data$obs~data$DOSE))[[1]][[5]][1]->pvalue
Allp<-rbind(Allp,pvalue)}
sum(Allp<=0.05)
```

And here I get the expected 5% .

Could you help me to solve that issue?

Best,
Simon

Comment: You should add `set.seed(number)` at the beginning so that we get the same answers. I got 2, for example.

Comment: Thx for your reply, lets use set.seed(1234) which gives 1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the problem. 
This was due to different mistakes:

1) you need to use factor(DOSE) in the anova

2) The way I simulated the dataset was incorrect:

```
data.frame(
obs=c(rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1)),
HOP=rep(rep(1:4,each=25),4),
DOSE=rep(c(0,15,30,50),each=100))->data
```

3) You need to take the impact of the HOP into account to get a proper estimation of the type one error:

```
set.seed(1234)
Allp<-NULL
for (i in 1:100){
data.frame(
obs=c(rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1),
rnorm(25,0,1),rnorm(25,1,1),rnorm(25,2,1),rnorm(25,3,1)),
HOP=rep(rep(1:4,each=25),4),
DOSE=rep(c(0,15,30,50),each=100))->data
summary(aov(data$obs~as.factor(data$DOSE)+as.factor(data$HOP)))[[1]][[5]][1]->pvalue
Allp<-rbind(Allp,pvalue)}
sum(Allp<=0.05)
```

Thanks for you time,
Simon